# LoginRequiredMixin not redirecting with TemplateView in django 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-templates

I am new to Django. I am trying to restrict the dashboard page using LoginRequiredMixin as described in the official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/. I am doing this with TemplateView. I also do it with View. But the problem is it always gives me access to this page although I remain logged out. I don't know what I have missed is just followed the documentation.

Here is my main url conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
              path('', include('user.urls')),
              path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
          ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is my dashboard urls conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

]

Here is my user urls conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

]

Here is my Dashboard view:

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
login_url = '/login'
redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
template_name = "user/dashboard.html"
```

Here is my login view:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
template_name = "user/login.html"
form_class = LoginForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

I searched in google and stack overflow also but that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure your log out view works correctly, and deletes the appropriate cookie?

Comment: I used  logout() method for logging out.

Comment: I am sorry actually this isn't logging out correctly. And I didn't check if the user is logged out or not. It kills me approximately 4 hours. Thanks this is now solved.

Comment: As an aside, you should add a trailing slash `login_url = '/login/'` so that it matches the URL pattern. Alternatively you could use the URL name `'login'` (include the app name if you set `app_name` in your `urls.py`, e.g. `'myapp:login'`).

Comment: @Alasdair thanks it's solved my other problem. Actually I want to redirect the login page but it changes the URL like ?redirect_to='/dashboard/'. I don't want that extra query param. after adding namespacing it's gone. thanks at all.

Comment: The `?next=/dashboard/` is useful, it means the user will be redirected back to the dashboard URL after they have logged in. You might be able to disable that feature, but I would suggest you keep it.

Comment: @Alasdair would you please tell me how to disable this feature? I want to learn.

Comment: Try setting `redirect_field_name = None`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove trailing slash from the dashboard app urls.py

It will work.

if you have **dashboard urls.py like this.**

```
urlpatterns = [
               path('user/', ...., .....)
```

]

Make it like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
                   path('user', ...., .....)  <-- Note here
]
```

Hope it will work.